# Numerical integration with parameter and plot

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I'm working on this function:

```
(0.0027 Sin[phi])/(1.05*Exp[-241w]+ Exp[239w]-Cos[phi])
```

I'd want `NIntegrate` this function on `w` leaving `phi` free and then plot on `phi`, but I don't know how I can. Can you help me please?

Comment: hint start with  `f[phi_?NumericQ]:=NIntegrate..` then plot f.

Answer (score 1):

Following suggestion above, and dropping 0.0027, as well introducing some additional parameters we get

```
   Intf[(phi_)?NumericQ, (a_)?NumericQ, (b_)?NumericQ] := 
   NIntegrate[ Sin[phi*Pi]/(a*Exp[(-b)*w] + Exp[239*w] - Cos[phi*Pi]), {w, 0, 0.1}]

   Manipulate[ListLinePlot[Table[{t, Intf[t, e, b]}, 
   {t, 0.01, 1, 0.05}]], {e, 0.5, 1.5}, {b, 100, 400}]
```

[image]

`phi` is given in terms of Pi